# Fontastic not loading on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I have a live site at http://www.factormedia.co.za

When you inspect it to phone scale (around 350px width or so) it loads 3 icons in the menu, of a house,laptop and notepad.

However if you had to actually use a phone the images do not appear. So trying to figure out why it is not referencing my font library from fontastic.com.
Works fine in a preview but on the actual device itself.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm currently having the same issue, I can't see the icons on mobile devices

Comment: @Greg found solution check in answers

Comment: This is another solution answered on my question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554728/fontastic-me-not-working-on-mobile/33573750#33573750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you embed using the link they give you works when testing and using anything from a laptop to a desktop, once you scale down it starts to give issues to mobile. To solve this issue the easiest way was to manually download the icons I was using and use them as their own custom font by installing it as the site instructs.

This then solved the problem and it now shows on smaller devices

Comment: Good solution, will use this next time when it doesn't show up. It looks like fontastic fixed the bug because the icons show up again