# Fontastic.me not working on mobile

Tags: svg, fontastic

`Fontastic.me` is a website that let you upload `svg` files so you can use your `icons` as a font. I've used this site lots of times, but today I noticed the icons are not working on `mobile` anymore. They do work in the `browsers` on computer. I only noticed it today, it has always worked before.

You can use this [link](http://www.gregorycourtens.be) to test on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like a bug in the Fontastic CSS generator: your page links CSS

`https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/8pMGtiqubDqmpbD4ER7hE3/icons.css`

this contains last SVG fallback linked as

`https://cdn.myfontastic.com/8pMGtiqubDqmpbD4ER7hE3/fonts/1446830181.svg#1446830181`

the hash part of the URL must correspond with font ID in the SVG, but actual source contains `<font id="cloud-font" horiz-adv-x="512">` instead.

So replacing  `#14468301` with `#cloud-font` in CSS or replacing @id value in SVG should fix your problem.

This applies only for case your mobile really resorts to SVG version. Only few browsers would do that (I think Android below 4.4, maybe old Safari, Blackberry, and maybe Opera Mobile).

---

(Besides that, your HTML contains extra HEAD tag with icon CSS link in BODY, what [is not valid](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.gregorycourtens.be&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  I donʼt think this will make any sane browser completely ignore the link, but cannot exclude such possibility.  If you have served your page as real `application/xhtml+xml`, browser should show the error right away.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm aware of the extra HEAD tags. The website is made in Drupal and didn't know back then Drupal already has a template for that, so it's double now. I should change it

Answer (score 1):

Greg, i had the same issue.  I end up ditching Fontastic and use https://glyphter.com/ instead.

Glyphter creates your own font set by uploading each character at a time.

It worked for me and perhaps you can try this too and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this one before. Will definitely check it out

Comment: Hi Greg, I actually went to your site and saw that your fonts are not working.  I like Glyphter bc you don't need to load up all the glphs you won't use.  You only create those you want, then it creates the font files for you. Helps to keep things optimize and load fast :D

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely change to Glyphter now haha